# inverted page curl when the device is rotated

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a very little view that I am animating with a page curl like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
```

It works well, the view curls up from the right but if I rotate the device 180 degrees the curl happens from the left.

My app supports both landscape orientations. No portrait allowed.

How to solve that?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227186/73195

Comment: sorry but this is not a solution for this answer. Obviously the problem is related to the device rotation, but how do I solve that?

Comment: Have u supported both portrait and landscape orientation? u can refer http://gigaom.com/2009/04/08/iphone-dev-sessions-how-to-make-an-orientation-aware-clock/ for more details on orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all 
Have you tried using:

```
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
```

Is this your problem :

When you're doing "curl up" in landscape mode,with the button on the right, the page starts to flip from top right to bottom left (meaning, your turned the page with your right hand, and moved toward the left side of the book. also meaning that the book's binding is on the left).

When you're doing the very same, but with button on the left, the animation don't rotate, even when correctly rotating content, saying "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation : True" in the vc. As a result the animation goes from bottom left to top right, giving the impression that the book's binding now is on the right.

Some code to illustrate that :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        view1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [view1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:80]];
        [view1 setText:@"VIEW 1"];

        view2 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        [view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [view2 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:80]];
        [view2 setText:@"VIEW 2"];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)didSwipeNext
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(swipePrevious) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)didSwipePrevious
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(swipeNext) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)swipeNext
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"curl" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(didSwipeNext)];

    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)swipePrevious
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"curl" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(didSwipePrevious)];

    [view2 removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(swipeNext) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

A walk-around is to create a wrapper(UIView) for all UI elements in the page to be purled. I've make the wrapper the only subview of the view controller's view and all other views subview of the wrapper. And modify the target to wrapper as below

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.wrapperView
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                animations:^{[imageView setImage:foregroundImage];} 
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!! problem solved. Can you explain why? If this wrapper is inside the viewcontroller's subview why it is not subject to the same problem?

Comment: The behaviour described is probably due to a bug.